# Ошибка: Имя "pydoc" не распознано

Tags: python, python-3.x

Библиотека не имеет своей онлайн-документации, а просит почитать её через pydoc.
Строка в терминале VS Code `pydoc texterra` возвращает

```
pydoc : Имя "pydoc" не распознано как имя командлета, функции, файла сценария или выполняемой программы. Проверьте правильность написания имени, а также наличие и правильность пути, после чего повторите попытку.
строка:1 знак:1
+ pydoc texterra
+ ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pydoc:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

В cmd - `"pydoc" не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.`
Пробовал добавлять путь AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib в Path как системную переменную - не помогло. Прошу помочь(
Python версии 3.10.8

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: А в VSC выбрано правильное окружение? (Справа внизу.)

Comment: @CrazyElf, вроде бы да
https://imgur.com/a/DeBXR6V

Comment: Как вариант пробуйте запускать через `python -m pydoc`. И еще попробуйте в Path добавить `AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts`